# Word Embedding Model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, word2vec, word-embedding, fasttext

I have been searching and attempting to implement a word embedding model to predict similarity between words. I have a dataset made up 3,550 company names, the idea is that the user can provide a new word (which would not be in the vocabulary) and calculate the similarity between the new name and existing ones.

During preprocessing I got rid of stop words and punctuation (hyphens, dots, commas, etc). In addition, I applied stemming and separated prefixes with the hope to get more precision. Then words such as `BIOCHEMICAL` ended up as `BIO` `CHEMIC` which is the word divided in two (prefix and stem word)

The average company name length is made up 3 words with the following frequency:

[image]

The tokens that are the result of preprocessing are sent to word2vec:

```
#window: Maximum distance between the current and predicted word within a sentence
#min_count: Ignores all words with total frequency lower than this.
#workers: Use these many worker threads to train the model
#sg: The training algorithm, either CBOW(0) or skip gram(1). Default is 0s
word2vec_model = Word2Vec(prepWords,size=300, window=2, min_count=1, workers=7, sg=1)
```

After the model included all the words in the vocab , the average sentence vector is calculated for each company name:
    df['avg_vector']=df2.apply(lambda row : avg_sentence_vector(row, model=word2vec_model, num_features=300, index2word_set=set(word2vec_model.wv.index2word)).tolist())

Then, the vector is saved for further lookups:

```
##Saving name and vector values in file
df.to_csv('name-submission-vectors.csv',encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

If a new company name is not included in the vocab after preprocessing (removing stop words and punctuation), then I proceed to create the model again and calculate the average sentence vector and save it again.

I have found this model is not working as expected. As an example, calculating the most similar words `pet` is getting the following results:

```
ms=word2vec_model.most_similar('pet')

('fastfood', 0.20879755914211273)
('hammer', 0.20450574159622192)
('allur', 0.20118337869644165)
('wright', 0.20001833140850067)
('daili', 0.1990675926208496)
('mgt', 0.1908089816570282)
('mcintosh', 0.18571510910987854)
('autopart', 0.1729743778705597)
('metamorphosi', 0.16965581476688385)
('doak', 0.16890916228294373)
```

In the dataset, I have words such as paws or petcare, but other words are creating relationships with `pet` word.

This is the distribution of the nearer words for `pet`:

[image]

On the other hand, when I used the `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz`, I could not add new words to the vocab, but the similarity between `pet` and words around was as expected:

```
ms=word2vec_model.most_similar('pet')
('pets', 0.771199643611908)
('Pet', 0.723974347114563)
('dog', 0.7164785265922546)
('puppy', 0.6972636580467224)
('cat', 0.6891531348228455)
('cats', 0.6719794869422913)
('pooch', 0.6579219102859497)
('Pets', 0.636363685131073)
('animal', 0.6338439583778381)
('dogs', 0.6224827170372009)
```

This is the distribution of the nearest words:

[image]

I would like to get your advice about the following:

- Is this dataset appropriate to proceed with this model?
- Is the length of the dataset enough to allow `word2vec` "learn" the relationships between the words?
- What can I do to improve the model to make `word2vec` create relationships of the same type as GoogleNews where for instance word `pet` is correctly set among similar words?
- Is it feasible to implement another alternative such as `fasttext` considering the nature of the current dataset?
- Do you know any public dataset that can be used along with the current dataset to create those relationships?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3500 texts (company names) of just ~3 words each is only around 10k total training words, with a much smaller vocabulary of unique words.

That's very, very small for word2vec & related algorithms, which rely on lots of data, and sufficiently-varied data, to train-up useful vector arrangements.

You may be able to squeeze some meaningful training from limited data by using *far more* training epochs than the default `epochs=5`, and *far smaller* vectors than the default `size=100`. With those sorts of adjustments, you may start to see more meaningful `most_similar()` results.

But, it's unclear that word2vec, and specifically word2vec in your averaging-of-a-name's-words comparisons, is matched to your end goals.

Word2vec needs lots of data, doesn't look at subword units, and can't say anything about word-tokens not seen during training. An average-of-many-word-vectors can often work as an easy baseline for comparing multiword texts, but might also dilute some word's influence compared to other methods.

Things to consider might include:

- Word2vec-related algorithms like FastText that also learn vectors for subword units, and can thus bootstrap not-so-bad guess vectors for words not seen in training. (But, these are also data hungry, and to use on a small dataset you'd again want to reduce vector size, increase epochs, and additionally shrink the number of `buckets` used for subword learning.)
- More sophisticated comparisons of multi-word texts, like "Word Mover's Distance". (That can be quite expensive on longer texts, but for names/titles of just a few words may be practical.)
- Finding more data that's compatible with your aims for a stronger model. A larger database of company names might help. If you just want your analysis to understand English words/roots, more generic training texts might work too.
- For many purposes, a mere lexicographic comparison - edit distances, count of shared character-n-grams – may be helpful too, though it won't detect all synonyms/semantically-similar words.

Answer (score 1):

Word2vec does not generalize to unseen words.

It does not even work well for wards that are seen but *rare*. It really depends on having many many examples of word usage. Furthermore a you need enough context left and right, but you only use company names - these are too short. That is likely why your embeddings perform so poorly: too little data and too short texts.

Hence, it is the wrong approach for you. Retraining the model with the new company name is not enough - you still only have one data point. You may as well leave out unseen words, word2vec *cannot* work better than that even if you retrain.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to compute similarity between words, probably you don't need to insert new words in your vocabulary.

By eye, I think you can also use FastText without the need to stem the words. It also computes vectors for unknown words.

From [FastText FAQ](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/faqs.html):

> One of the key features of fastText word representation is its ability
>   to produce vectors for any words, even made-up ones. Indeed, fastText
>   word vectors are built from vectors of substrings of characters
>   contained in it. This allows to build vectors even for misspelled
>   words or concatenation of words.

FastText seems to be useful for your purpose.
For your task, you can follow [FastText supervised tutorial](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html).

If your corpus proves to be too small, you can build your model starting from availaible pretrained vectors ([pretrainedVectors parameter](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/python-module.html#train_supervised-parameters)).